# Would it be possible to use a laptop that has USB-C (DisplayPort or similar) as a display for another device?

Tags: usb, usb-c, displaylink

I am wondering: Now that video is delivered over USB-C (I suppose over DisplayPort but I don’t know if there are other protocols as well), would it be possible to use a laptop as display for another device, and use a client application as a windowed display?

Comment: It might be good to be a little more specific with your setup. I don't know much about this but you might need to mess with drivers and stuff

Answer (score 1):

There is a video signal on USB-C, but it's not over the USB protocol, it's over DisplayPort protocol which are physically separate lines.

USB-C basically is a USB + Display Port on a single connector (+ power and other cool stuffs).

There are some devices that output on USB, like webcams, but that is not necessarily related to USB-C.

If you want to handle the native USB-C video signal (so the display port), you will need some sort of acquisition card for that or specialized hardware. USB-C computers are not designed to handle video input from the USB-C display port, but can handle video input from the USB protocol (webcam).

Comment: How about devices supporting displaylink? Would it be possible in that case, or over thundebolt?

Answer (score -1):

Type-C port is currently designed to OUTPUT display port data. To get it as a simple input, a special capturing device is needed, with interface to USB. There is no such devices on the market AFAIK.

Technically, Type-C connector can be used in both directions, obviously. However, to make the laptop port to be as an endpoint of DisplayPort, the connectivity protocol must be amended to include the DP as receiver. To do so, (a) DP hardware block needs to be integrated into laptops, and (b) capability negotiation protocol (which is done as a part of Power Delivery messaging system) needs to be expanded. It will require new revision of specifications. With new USB4 specifications (tunneling of all sorts of serial protocol over a single link) an extension of DP "ALT mode 2" to switch data direction should be easier, although I have not heard about this effort yet.

However, you can use your laptop as a second display, there are several other methods, over network:
[How to Use A Laptop as A Monitor](https://techguided.com/how-to-use-a-laptop-as-a-monitor/)
and [How to Use Your Laptop Like an External Monitor](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-laptop-like-external-monitor/)